# Logic exception when using formfield in symfony

Tags: php, symfony, twig, form-fields

I'm trying to use this `DatePicker` form type in my `Twig` form:
https://github.com/mohebifar/DateTimeBundle
Using `jquery` widget as described here:
https://github.com/mohebifar/DateTimeBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/2.3-date-picker-form-type.md

Like this:

```
{% block headassets %}
    {% stylesheets 'bundles/itwuser/css/*.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
    {% endstylesheets %}

    {{ form_datetime_css(form) }}
    {{ form_datetime_js_asset(form) }}
    {{ form_datetime_js(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

But I'm getting this `LogicException` at the line `form_datetime_css(form)`

```
LogicException: Unable to render the form as none of the following blocks exist: "_itw_userbundle_user_css", "itw_userbundle_user_css", "form_css".
```

What is the problem?

---

Update:
I added the theme:

```
{% form_theme form 'MohebifarDateTimeBundle::form_fields.html.twig' %}
```

But still same exception occurs!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me like missing form theme. I would assume that this bundle came with written theme which extends the basic but also adds the those blocks.

If you're unfamiliar with form themes please see this link: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-2-inside-a-separate-template

Comment: I added the theme with `{% form_theme form 'MohebifarDateTimeBundle::form_fields.html.twig' %}
` but still getting same exception!

Comment: Did you do it before invoking `form_datetime_css`?

Comment: Yes, at the beginning of the file.